# How to display Notice successfull in postgres

Tags: postgresql, exception, plpgsql

I want to display in my CMD console, ONLY the success message if my request its OK:

Example :

```
  BEGIN
  INSERT / UPDATE .... //request
  EXCEPTION
  WHEN successful_completion THEN RAISE NOTICE 'INFO : MESSAGE RESQUEST IS OK ';
  END;
```

THIS MY CODE EDIT:

```
        DO $$ 
            BEGIN
                BEGIN
                    UPDATE user set age = 22 , date_inscription =  '2018-01-30' where id = 154;
                EXCEPTION
                WHEN ??? THEN ????
               END;
               RAISE NOTICE 'INFO : L''age  et date inscription ont été mis à jour';  // MESSAGE OK
            END;
            $$
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no message `successful_completion`, but I guess you know that.

- If you want to send a notice on error, put it into the exception handler.
- If you want to send a notice on success, put the `RAISE` *after* the SQL statement in question.
- If you want to send a notice no matter what, put the `RAISE` after the whole block.

An example for the second option:

```
BEGIN
   INSERT ...
   RAISE NOTICE 'INFO : MESSAGE REQUEST IS OK ';
EXCEPTION
   WHEN OTHERS THEN
      /* handle the error */
END;
```

Comment: OK, i put what in exception "EXCEPTION
   WHEN ... THEN ..." ?
I edit my post, you can to see my example.

Comment: No, you have to do it like in my answer: put the `RAISE` after the block, that is, after the closing `END`.

Comment: Ok, but I do not know what to wear in the bloc "WHEN ??? THEN ???". I modified my post

Comment: Come on, this isn't so hard. All you have to do is to read the documentation. If you want to ignore the error, just add `WHEN OTHERS THEN NULL;` in the exception handler.

Comment: this code send RAISE NOTICE 'INFO : MESSAGE REQUEST IS OK' in all cases. !! 
I am novice and the documentation postgres seems to me incomplete on this subject.

Comment: No need for exclamation marks. Your English is so bad that I have trouble understanding you. I have revised the answer again. Now the message is only displayed if the `INSERT` is successful.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to prevent having the notice `INFO : MESSAGE REQUEST IS OK` in case of failure, you should but it just between the `INSERT` statement and the `EXCEPTION` block, as here:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test_notice (int_id INTEGER) RETURNS integer AS
$do$
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO tbl VALUES (int_id);
   RAISE NOTICE 'INFO : MESSAGE REQUEST IS OK ';
   RETURN 0;
EXCEPTION
   WHEN OTHERS THEN
      RAISE NOTICE 'Ignoring error';
      RETURN 1;
END;
$do$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Here is the DDL for the `tbl` table:

```sql
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tbl;
CREATE TABLE tbl (id int);
ALTER TABLE tbl ADD CONSTRAINT tbl_pk PRIMARY KEY (id);
```

And here is a test case, with 1 success, 1 failure and then 1 success:

```sql
()=#SELECT test_notice (1);
NOTICE:  INFO : MESSAGE REQUEST IS OK 
test_notice 
-------------
          0
(1 row)

()=#SELECT test_notice (1);
NOTICE:  Ignoring error
test_notice 
-------------
          1
(1 row)

()=#SELECT test_notice (2);
NOTICE:  INFO : MESSAGE REQUEST IS OK 
test_notice 
-------------
          0
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 other methods available if you insist on actually checking, other than retrieving a row from the processed set. First both Insert and Update set FOUND True if a row was processed and False otherwise. The other is to get the actual number of rows processed via [Get Diagnostics](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/plpgsql-statements.html). The following block demonstrates both.

```
do $$
   declare rows_processed integer; 
begin 
   insert into users(id, age, date_inscription)
          values  (154, 20, now()::date)
               ,  (164, 22, now()::date);
   get diagnostics rows_processed = row_count;
   raise notice '1. After Insert: Found=%, Num of Rows=%', found, rows_processed;

   UPDATE users 
      set age = age+2 , date_inscription = now()::date
    where id  in (154, 160) ;  -- one of two
   get diagnostics rows_processed = row_count;    
   raise notice '2. After Update: Found=%, Num of Rows=%', found, rows_processed;

   UPDATE users 
      set age = 12 , 
      date_inscription =  now()::date
      where id = 205;
   get diagnostics rows_processed = row_count;      
   raise notice '3. After Update (no such id): Found=%, Num of Rows=%', found, rows_processed;

   delete from users;
   get diagnostics rows_processed = row_count;      
   raise notice '4. After Delete: Found=%, Num of Rows=%', found, rows_processed;   
end;
$$;
```